# beautiful websites using Emacs's org mode

Tags: emacs, responsive-design, web, org-mode

Are there any beautiful websites published using Emacs' org mode? I followed the online tutorial, but the generated websites are too ugly. Are there any existing beautiful org templates (with nice css sheets)?

Comment: http://orgmode.org is published with Org.  But I guess it does not qualify as "beautiful".

Comment: Does [this](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html) fit the bill?

Comment: @bzg that's not bad. but where can I read the .org file? Thanks

Comment: git clone git://orgmode.org/orgweb.git

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My site isn't generated from OrgMode, but from Muse, and you can re-use [parts of my templates](http://alexott.net/en/writings/EmacsMuseMyPage.html) - I took one of free designs by [Andreas Viklund](http://andreasviklund.com/).

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question that was asked.

Comment: if you don't know, Muse & Org-mode are very close to each other, that's why I pointed to my site

Answer (score 27):

I create my class websites using org-mode. Example: http://cse3521.artifice.cc/

That site involves regular text, code, math, flash/image embeds, tables, etc.

Source code is available here: https://github.com/joshuaeckroth/cse3521-website

Comment: Very nice site material -- but if I am not mistaken, the master file (index.org) is not included in the github repo. I would like to see how it is done!

Comment: The index.html is manually created. I wanted to decide the layout, indentation of the topic list, etc.

Comment: This is great. I am using the template for my course work. Thanks.

Comment: Ditto from me. Thanks for providing this!

Answer (score 10):

There is http://msnyder.info which uses org-mode and I think is nicely styled.  However, he also customizes the publishing system to get HTML5 output and better styling.  Read more about that [here](http://msnyder.info/posts/2011/07/introducing-narcissus/).

Comment: @JimGarrison back online as it seems :)

Answer (score 9):

You could simply use the Solarized CSS which gives you appealing results including nice usability enhancement (like collapsable sections).

See
  http://thomasf.github.io/solarized-css/

To appy to any org-mode HTML export add the following lines in your .emacs:

```
 (setq org-export-html-style-include-scripts nil
       org-export-html-style-include-default nil)
 (setq org-export-html-style
   "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"solarized-light.css\" />")
```

Answer (score 7):

Fresh and new template (I found it on the mailing list):

https://github.com/fniessen/org-html-themes

Answer (score 6):

I just created new github repository for the template to use org-mode + jekyll + twitter bootstrap.

Check out http://github.com/cinsk/jekyll-org/ for the source, and see the example in http://cinsk.github.com/jekyll-org/

Answer (score 6):

Go through official org-mode page listing sites : [Web pages made with Org-Mode](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-web.html)

Answer (score 4):

I use org-mode + jekyll to publish my blog ([blog.jenkster.com](http://blog.jenkster.com)). 'Beautiful' is probably a stretch, but it's clean & clear, and the nicest setup I've ever found for including code-snippets in what I'm writing.

Answer (score 3):

My Web site at http://www.pirilampo.org/ is all made from Org mode (and only it). You'll find the CSS source there as well (LP'ed from an Org file with Org Babel -- LP = Literate Programming).

Answer (score 2):

How about [this page](http://www.gorgnegre.com/linux/using-emacs-orgmode-to-blog-with-jekyll.html#notebook)? It shows how to set up the combo Emacs Org-mode & Jekyll in order to publish a static website or blog ---This is what is used at [www.gorgnegre.com](http://www.gorgnegre.com). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I just read about Hyde, a static website generator powered by python & django.
http://ringce.com/hyde
To set it up is really easy and minimalistic.
We can use our favorite text editor to edit the content, hence org-mode.

Then I saw those two projects which intent to link even more org and hyde, but never tried :
https://github.com/dustinlacewell/ghorg
https://github.com/punchagan/org-hyde

That sounds very appealing to me !

Answer (score 1):

Here is my site http://sydi.org that generated by orgmode, but its language is not English but Chinese. I think weather a site is beautiful and fit your eyes or not isn't depend on which tool used to make pages out, more important, well designed css & js do that.

I use orgmode generate html and fix something by elisp (orgmode hooks) on origins. If you need any help, I'm very pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://renard.github.com/o-blog/ - it's not strictly using org-mode, but an org-mode add-on (and also the subject of the site) called o-blog.  I haven't done anything serious with it, but it looks pretty cool.  It easily integrates with twitter bootstrap for all the nice pretty things it provides.